# Example solr xml working fine but my own xml files not working

Tags: solr

Please find below necessary steps that executed.

Iam following same structure as mentioned by you, and checked  results in the admin page by clicking search button, samples are working fine.

Ex:Added monitor.xml and search for video its displaying results----- search content is displaying properly

Let me explain you the problem which iam facing:

step 1: I started Apache tomcat

step2 : Indexing Data
           java -jar post.jar myfile.xml

Here is my XML content:

```
<add>

     <doc>
          <field name="id">11111</field>
          <field name="name">Youth to Elder</field>
          <field name="Author"> Integrated Research Program</field>
          <field name="Year">2009</field>
          <field name="Publisher"> First Nation</field>
     </doc>
     <doc>
          <field name="id">22222</field>
          <field name="name">Strategies </field>
          <field name="Author">Implementation Committee </field>
          <field name="Year">2001</field>
          <field name="Publisher">Policy</field>

     </doc>

</add>
```

Step 4 : i did

```
     java -jar post.jar myfile.xml
```

output of above one:

SimplePostTool: version 1.2
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Make sure your XML documents are encoded in UTF-8, othe
r encodings are not currently supported
SimplePostTool: POSTing files to http://localhost:8983/solr/update..
SimplePostTool: POSTing file curnew.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: Solr returned an error: Bad Request

Request to help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [configure your schema](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml). The [default schema](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/releases/lucene-solr/3.1/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml) doesn't have any Author, Year or Publisher fields.

Comment: Please help me for, how to configure schema.xml for the above myfile.xml, in schema.xml different data types available(string,text,textgen), what type to put for name,Author,year,publisher